# Sql Azure , Truncate and Reseed All Tables

Tags: azure-sql-database

`DBCC` is not available in `Sql Azure` so basically we cant perform `DBCC` actions. So how we do the reset for identity in `Sql Azure`.

i written this to Truncate all records and Reseed the Tables to 1 and obviously this is not going to work cause `DBCC` is not Allowed.

```
EXEC sp_MSForEachTable ‘ALTER TABLE ? NOCHECK CONSTRAINT ALL’
EXEC sp_MSForEachTable ‘DELETE FROM ?’
EXEC sp_MSForEachTable ‘ALTER TABLE ? CHECK CONSTRAINT ALL’
DBCC checkident (?, RESEED, 1)  ??
GO
```

So how i do the Reseed with this script.

Comment: sp_msforeachtable is also not supported in Sql Azure. Here's an alternative: https://gist.github.com/metaskills/893599

Answer (score 4):

Here is what I did:

```
declare @dropConstraintsSql nvarchar(max);
declare @enableConstraintsSql nvarchar(max);
declare @deleteSql nvarchar(max);

-- create a string that contains all sql statements to drop contstraints 
-- the tables are selected by matching their schema_id and type ('U' is table)   

SELECT @dropConstraintsSql = COALESCE(@dropConstraintsSql + ';','') + 'ALTER TABLE [' + name + '] NOCHECK CONSTRAINT all'
FROM sys.all_objects 
WHERE type='U' and schema_id=1
-- AND... other conditions to match your tables 


-- create a string that contains all your DELETE statements...

SELECT @deleteSql = COALESCE(@deleteSql + ';','') + 'DELETE FROM [' + name + '] WHERE ...'
FROM sys.all_objects 
WHERE type='U' and schema_id=1
-- AND ... other conditions to match your tables 

-- create a string that contains all sql statements to reenable contstraints    

SELECT @enableConstraintsSql = COALESCE(@enableConstraintsSql + ';','') + 'ALTER TABLE [' + name + '] WITH CHECK CHECK CONSTRAINT all'
FROM sys.all_objects 
WHERE type='U' and schema_id=1
-- AND ... other conditions to match your tables 

-- in order to check if the sqls are correct you can ...
-- print @dropConstraintsSql
-- print @deleteSql
-- print @enableConstraintsSql


-- execute the sql statements in a transaction

begin tran 

exec sp_executesql  @dropConstraintsSql
exec sp_executesql  @deleteSql
exec sp_executesql  @enableConstraintsSql

-- commit if everything is fine
rollback
```

Comment: I get error when executing the scripts `Incorrect syntax near ';'.`

Comment: @Zapnologica You have to remove the "WHERE ...." clause or add a condition